# Cambiar color de un div cuando se hace scroll js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un nav con el id "navbar". Al igual que tiene la propiedad Fixed por lo cual siempre esta al top de la pagina,Que quiero que al hacer scroll hacia abajo, cambie de color por lo cual tengo el siguient metodo:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , () => {
        var element = document.getElementById("navbar");
        document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        element.setAttribute("style","background-color: rgba(255,255,255,10)");
        });
    });
```

Funciona, si, pero no se me ocurre la forma de hacer que cambie el color en una cierta cantidad de pixeles, al igual que en ves de hacer un `setAttribute` haga una incersion de una clase al elemento
PD: es js puro

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo hecho con paint o algo para ver el resultado de lo que deseas?

Comment: Lo que quiero lograr, es que mi nav al hacer digamos 120 de scroll hacia abajo, cambie de color rojo (color inicial) a color negro (color al llegar a los 120 de ScrollY) de igual manera, deja realizo un dibujo rapido de ello

Comment: Ya agrege la imagen, espero sea de ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pongo el código con JS puro, si lo ejecutas y lo scrolleas, podrás ver que cambia la clase y el color de fondo, ajústalo a tu código

```js
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
  var element = document.getElementById("nav");
  element.classList.add("change");
}
```

```css
div.nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  position :fixed;
}

.no-nav {
  overflow-y :scroll;
  height : 1000px;
}

.change {
  background-color : red !important;
}
```

```html
<body class="no-nav" height="1000px">
  <div id="nav" class="nav" width=100%>
    nav
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Prueba este código, cambia el estilo del `div` cuando llega a 200, tiene dos validaciones cuando el `scroll` llegue a 200 lo cambia de color , puedes poner un `console.log` a `scrollTop` para ver los valores que permite el `scroll`, ademas tiene una validacion para devolver el color al incial

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
 
  if(scrollTop >= 200){
    document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor='#C20000';
  }

 if(scrollTop < 200){
    document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor='#000000';
  }

});
```

```css
#test{
width: 50%;
height: 500px;
background:#000000;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```